# Video is not visible if rotated on android device in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am rotating my video by 90 degree.On android device no video is being displayed.I think the video is running in background but it is not visible.
On desktop video is visible even after rotation.

Here is my code:

```
 package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;

    public class VideoTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function VideoTest()
        {
            var nc:NetConnection= new NetConnection();
            //nc.objectEncoding=1
            nc.connect(null);

            var vid:Video = new Video(); 
            addChild(vid);
            vid.rotation=45;
            vid.x=100;
            var streamClient:Object = new Object();
            streamClient.onMetaData =  function onMetaData(infoObject:Object):void {
                /*for (var propName:String in infoObject) {
                trace(propName + " = " + infoObject[propName]);
                }*/
            };

            var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
            ns.client = streamClient;
            ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHandler); 
            ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler); 

            vid.attachNetStream(ns);

            ns.play("half girlfriend.mp4"); 
        }

        private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void 
        { 
            // handle netStatus events, described later 
        } 

        private function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void 
        { 
            // ignore error 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is an Adobe AIR app, i don't think you need to handle the rotation of the video yourself.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't do any rotating.  When device rotates, the stage is rotated automatically.  Auto rotation setting is in the publish settings.

Comment: I am making a video from my adobe air app but recorded video get rotated by -90 degree .So to play video in same angle in which the video has been recorded i need to rotate my video.